# Canvas drawImage layering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, canvas

Using a canvas to render a collection of images layered that a user can download the compiled image afterwards. However, when using `image.onload` it layers the order of images in terms of which loads the fastest from the CDN.

I am trying to achieve so that they are layered in terms of code line progression. Is there anyway to achieve this? I have tried async functions but haven't really been able to achieve anything. Below is the current code I have:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

interface CanvasProps {
    width: number;
    height: number;
    base: string;
    eyes: string;
    hat: string;
    backpack: string;
    clothes: string;
    selected: number;
}

const Canvas = ({ width, height, base, eyes, hat, backpack, clothes, selected }: CanvasProps) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

    const renderImages = async (context) => {
        var bg_image = new Image();
        var base_image = new Image();
        var eyes_image = new Image();
        var hats_image = new Image();
        var backpacks_image = new Image();
        var clothes_image = new Image();

        bg_image.crossOrigin="*";
        base_image.crossOrigin="*";
        eyes_image.crossOrigin="*";
        hats_image.crossOrigin="*";
        clothes_image.crossOrigin="*";
        backpacks_image.crossOrigin="*";

        base_image.src = base;
        eyes_image.src = eyes;
        hats_image.src = hat;
        clothes_image.src = backpack;
        backpacks_image.src = clothes;

        base_image.onload = function(){ context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 650, 650) }
        eyes_image.onload = function(){ context.drawImage(eyes_image, 0, 0, 650, 650) }
        hats_image.onload = function(){ context.drawImage(hats_image, 0, 0, 650, 650) }
        clothes_image.onload = function(){ context.drawImage(clothes_image, 0, 0, 650, 650) }
        backpacks_image.onload = function(){ context.drawImage(backpacks_image, 0, 0, 650, 650) }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (canvasRef.current) {
            const canvas = canvasRef.current;
            if (canvasRef.current) {
                const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                if (context) {
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, 650, 650);
                    renderImages(context);
                }
            }
        }       
    },[selected]);

    return <canvas id="canvas" ref={canvasRef} height={height} width={width} />;
};

Canvas.defaultProps = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
};

export default Canvas;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your image creation in a `Promise` that resolves once the image is done loading and wait for each of the image loadings to finish, to achieve the synchronous flow you want.

```js
const getImg = (url: string) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin="*";
  img.src = url;

  return new Promise((res, rej) =>  {
        img.onload = () => res(img);
        img.onerror = (err) => rej(err);
  });
}

const renderImages = async (context) => {
  const baseImg = await getImg(base);
  context.drawImage(baseImg, 0, 0, 650, 650);

  const eyesImg = await getImg(eyes);
  context.drawImage(eyesImg, 0, 0, 650, 650);

  const hatImg = await getImg(hat);
  context.drawImage(hatImg, 0, 0, 650, 650);

  const backpackImg = await getImg(backpack);
  context.drawImage(backpackImg, 0, 0, 650, 650);

  const clothesImg = await getImg(clothes);
  context.drawImage(clothesImg, 0, 0, 650, 650);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice ... remember the answer is not just for the person that is asking this now but also for any one in the future that might run into the same

Comment: Added an explanation in the first answer, noticed a minor issue, and edited it and I might have accidentally removed it. Re-added the explanation above

Answer (score 1):

I would use one array `image_sources` instead of a the many variables you are using
*(base, eyes, hat, backpack, clothes)*, benefits of this approach:

- This would significantly reduce the size of your render function code.
- We can recursively call `renderImages` to sequentially draw all
  images.
- Your code is ready to handle as many image layers as the
  users needs.

Here is my rough prototype:

```
const renderImages = (context, index) => {
  if (index < image_sources.length) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = "*";
    image.src = image_sources[index];
    image.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 650, 650)
      renderImages(context, index + 1)
    }
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (canvasRef.current) {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (context) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 650, 650);
        renderImages(context, 0);
      }
    }
  }
}, [selected]);
```